# Unit Testing with Func<something> as parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, func

How do I generate unit test for the following method within VS2010 ?

```
public bool myResult(Func<int, int, bool> myFunc)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;    
    return myFunc(a, b);
}
```

When I right-click and select "Generate Unit Tests..." the myResult method is not available to select for a unit test.  Methods that do not contain Func as parameters do appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the automatic test generator doesn't work, you can just make the unit test manually.

All that is required is to have a method that's flagged with [`[TestMethod]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx) in your class, and write the unit test(s) yourself.

Comment: Yes, this manual method does work.  I was curious about auto-generation and why VS2010 was not including these methods.  I found that if the class is **public** VS2010 will auto-generate the tests with `Func<>` parameters